# ID conversion from Drosophila Gene Symbols to Human Gene Symbols

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I am looking for an R solution (or a general logic solution) to convert Drosophila melanogaster gene ids into Homo sapiens gene ids. Using R/BiomaRt is problematic, due to the ever-changing nature of the BiomaRt dataset, and its dependence on an internet connection and server status.

The gene ids are in the FlyBase format, but I also have human-friendly gene symbols, e.g.

```
FBgn0259938 cwo
FBgn0036285 toe
FBgn0264490 Eip93F
FBgn0034903 sona
```

Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you can use the FlyBase orthologs table, which is periodically updated and also has DIOPT scores for each ortholog: ftp://ftp.flybase.net/releases/current/precomputed_files/orthologs/dmel_human_orthologs_disease_fb_2020_06.tsv.gz

Comment: Dear Nbals, yes, that is precisely what I was looking for! I will load it into R and use it. Just one point: to download it I had to right-click on the link and click on "open link in a new tab"